# How do I access the value of a promise object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Hi I have an async call to firebase which returns a promise and I would like to assign the value of the promise to a scope variable am not able to do it.

```
$scope.submitQuestion = function(){
    $scope.post.createdTime = createdtime;
    $scope.post.creator = $scope.user.profile.username;
    $scope.post.creatorUID = $scope.user.uid;
    $scope.post.creatorpic = $scope.user.profile.userpic;
    $scope.post.postmedia = $scope.object.video.info.uuid;

    $scope.post.postcountupdate = PostCount.getpostcount().$loaded().then(function(data){
        var postunivcount = 0;
        postunivcount = data.$value;
        var  postnewcount = postunivcount + 1 ;
        console.log('new count')

        $scope.postidcount = postnewcount;
        PostCount.updatepostcount(postnewcount);
        return postnewcount;
    });
```

This gives me a Promise with `$$state > value : 25`
I would like to assign the value `25` to `$scope.post.postcountupdate`

Can you please tell me how to accomplish this ?

I tried to assign the value to Scope with `$scope.postidcount = postnewcount;` and assign the scope value to the post object but that gives me `undefined` until the `$loaded` resolves which causes the submit action to work after two clicks !

Any help on this will be appreciated !

Comment: You're already assigning it to `$scope.postidcount`?

Comment: yes .. but when I assign it to $scope.post object it works in two steps .. at first it gets an 'undefined' cos it is not resolved yet and then gets assigned .

Comment: Yes of course, because it's asynchronous. You won't be able to change that.